# How to train a Chinese segmenter model by Stanford NLP Tools

Tags: java, nlp, classification, stanford-nlp

I am new to the Stanford CoreNLP Tools. Now I do not get an excellent segment result in Chinese, so I want to change the granulity of the Segmenter. I thought I could do this by training my own dict.

I downloaded the [`trainSegmenter-20080521`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/trainSegmenter-20080521.tar.gz) file, and follow the `trainSegmenter-20080521/README.txt`.

This is the README.txt:

```
Sat Jun 21 00:57:22 2008
Author: Pi-Chuan Chang

Here's a documentation of how to train and test the segmenter on specific split 
range of the CTB data.

The following steps assumes you have 3 files defining the ranges of train/dev/test.
They should be named as "ctb6.train", "ctb6.dev", "ctb6.test" respectively.
The format should be like:
      chtb_0003.fid
      chtb_0015.fid
      ...

[STEP 1] change the CTB6 path in the Makefile:
      CTB6=/afs/ir/data/linguistic-data/Chinese-Treebank/6/

[STEP 2] download and uncompress the lastest segmenter from:
      http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-chinese-segmenter-2008-05-21.tar.gz
and change this path in the Makefile to your local path:
      SEGMENTER=/tmp/stanford-chinese-segmenter-2008-05-21/

[STEP 3] simply type:
      make all
You can also split down into these sub-steps:
      make internaldict # make internal dictionaries for affixation feaetures
      make data         # make datasets
      make traintest    # train & test the CRF segmenter
```

But I still have some problems:

1. What is the format of the training file and what is `train/dev/test` each for?
2. What is the `chtb_0003.fid`, `chtb_0015.fid` and so on?
3. What is the `CTB6 path` in the Makefile, it seems that I shoud change the variable `CTB6` into `/afs/ir/data/linguistic-data/Chinese-Treebank/6/`. But it is aready there and it seems not a valid subpath.

By the way, there are many properties should be set for special demands, e.g., `sighanPostProcessing` and `serDictionary`.

Is there somewhere I can get all of those properties and their explanation?

All I can do now is to read the source code, e.g., `edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.SeqClassifierFlags.java`, but I still get confused with these property flags.

So appreciated for anyone's help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would ignore that README.  The information in it is fairly out of date.

A more recent explanation is here:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/segmenter-faq.shtml

The expected input format is one sentence per line with already segmented text on each line.  If you get your segmented data from parse trees, there are tools which will convert from parse tree to segmented text.

If there are particular sentences which aren't segmented correctly, it may be because it is using the CTB segmentation standard and you would prefer something different.  It may also be because of words that the segmenter doesn't know about.  If you send example sentences which follow the CTB segmentation standard to java-nlp-user, those unknown words will eventually make their way into the segmenter's training data.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps contacting Pi-Chuan Chang is your best bet for a final answer, but I did look into this a little bit. Answering your questions as best I can:

1. The format of the train/dev/test sets are in the format of the Chinese treebank; I gather it's version 6: https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2007T36
2. The *.fid files look to be parse trees for sentences. The format is something like below (note that my text editor is not displaying Chinese characters correctly):

   <DOC>
   <DOCID>XIN19981227.0018</DOCID>
   <HEADER>
   <DATE>1998-12-27</DATE>
   </HEADER>
   <BODY>
   <HEADLINE>
   <S ID=6470>
   ( (IP-HLN (NP-SBJ (NP-PN (NR <D6><D0><B9><FA>))
                     (ADJP (JJ <C3><F1><D3><AA>))
                     (NP (NN <BF><C6><BC><BC>)
                         (NN <C6><F3><D2><B5>)))
             (VP (VV <B2><BD><C8><EB>)
                 (NP-OBJ (PU <A1><B0>)
                         (NN <BB><C6><BD><F0>)
                         (NN <CA><B1><B4><FA>)
                         (PU <A1><B1>)))))
   </S>
   </HEADLINE>
   <TEXT>
   <P>
   <S ID=6471>
   ((FRAG (NR <D0><C2><BB><AA><C9><E7>)
                (NR <C9><EE><DB><DA>)
                (NT <CA><AE><B6><FE><D4><C2>)
                (NT <B6><FE><CA><AE><C6><DF><C8><D5>)
                (NN <B5><E7>)
                (PU <A3><A8>)
                (NN <BC><C7><D5><DF>)
                (NR <BA><CE><B9><E3><BB><B3>)
                (NR <D5><C5><CF><C8><B9><FA>)
                    (PU <A3><A9>)))
   </S>
   ...
3. The path given in the README is the local path on the Stanford machines. This will not be the correct path. You should change it to something local, and then put the treebank (https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2007T36) there. Note that you need an LDC license for this!

Comment: Thank a lot for @gaborangeli 's answer, for training Chinese Segmenter Model, things may be the same like you said. And do you have any ideas about the Flags for running Stanford CoreNLP Tools. I try my best but still get little infomation about these running Flags.